# ConnectAsync from Windows.Devices.WiFi.WiFiAdapter does not work if I'm not logged in

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, wifi

#### Issue:

As the title already says; connecting to a newtork using Windows.Devices.WiFi.WiFiAdapter does not seem to work if I'm not already logged in to the PC.

Does anyone have any ideas on why it doesn't work? Or if there are any other workarounds?

#### Some background:

I've created a console application using *Windows.Devices.WiFi.Adapter* API to connect to our wireless network automatically in certain situations, such as at startup and logons.

I connect using the following code:

```
switch (available_network.SecuritySettings.NetworkAuthenticationType)
{
    case NetworkAuthenticationType.Open80211:
    case NetworkAuthenticationType.None:
    case NetworkAuthenticationType.Unknown:
        task_connect = Program.MainAdapter.ConnectAsync(available_network, reconnectionKind).AsTask();
        break;
    default:
        task_connect = Program.MainAdapter.ConnectAsync(available_network, reconnectionKind, Program.Credentials).AsTask();
        break;
}
```

The application works fine when I'm logged in to Windows 10, but not while logged out, or from a command line started as another user. This severely limits the possibilities on what I can do with it.
I tried setting it up so it logs in at startup via a scheduled task (using the System account) but while the application runs, can find wireless networks, and tries to connect, it always fails with status *NetworkNotAvailable*.

I've tried two computers. Both have the same OS version: 21H1 (19043.1348)

**Source files:**
My application is heavily based on (copy pasted from) https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/blob/master/Samples/WiFiConnector/CS/README.md

My source files are here: https://github.com/henricbjork2liu/wifish

Comment: Is the machine connected to the network when you are not logged in?  Try from another machine a PING to the machine and see if there is a connection to network.

Comment: I have connected it to wired network for now, so technically yes. But it disconnects from the WiFi as soon as I log out.

Comment: I tested with another wireless network that's not password protected and I was able to login to it via my application while logged out from Windows. I don't know if the Windows WiFi API has issues connecting to password protected networks while logged out, or if it's this specific network. I'll continue my troubleshooting and will update this thread when I know more.